# How do I run a python file that takes a text file as input?

Tags: python, command-line

So basically I'm trying to run a python file in command line that reads a text file and displays the information.

I guess part of this question is also should the text file be in the same directory as the python file?

This is what I have and I believe it is correct as far as the code side.

```
  def print_words(filename):
        input_file = open(filename, 'r')
        print (input_file)

   print_words(filename)
```

Comment: If the file name is the full path, e.g. `filename = "C:\folder\folder\file.txt"` it doesn't have to be in the same folder as the script, since you explicitly passed the path in.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
import sys

def print_words(file_name):
    input_file = open(file_name, 'r')
    lines = input_file.readlines()
    lines = ' '.join(x for x in lines)
    print(lines)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    print_words(sys.argv[1])
```

The `filename` can be just the file name when it is in the same folder as the `.py` file. Otherwise the full path as `filename` will work as well.

edit: sys.argv[1] takes the second command line argument as `filename`. This can be the absolute or relative `filename`.

eg:
In Windows when the file is in the Python folder you can call in the command line:
    c:\Python32>python print_words.py "example.txt"

If the file is located somewhere elsewhere this works:
    c:\Python32>python print_words.py "C:\FOLDER\SUBFOLDER\example.txt"

Comment: So when I change print_words(filename) to print_words(fullPath) it runs without errors, but what would I have to do if I wanted to changed the input file while running it from the command line?

Answer (score 0):

Writing command line script starts with simple requirement like yours (let me enter just a filename) and soon leads to more complex scenarios.

At that moment some command line argument parser comes handy.

There are many options, some being:

- `sys.argv`: not command line parser, comes short in more complex situations
- `argparse`: part of stdlib since Python 2.7, but will require many lines of extra code
- `plac`: very handy for utility scripts, unless you have more complex situations
- `docopt`: so far the best and cleanest way to handle command line parsing I have found

### Command line parsing with `docopt`

First install docopt:

```
$ pip install docopt
```

Then write your script `readfile.py`

```
"""Read file (and possibly convert lines)
Usage:
    readfile.py [(--uppercase|--lowercase|--swapcase)] [--reverse] <filename>...
    readfile.py -h

Options:
    -U --uppercase  Convert text to uppercase
    -L --lowercase  Convert text to lowercase
    -S --swapcase   Swap character cases
    -R --reverse    Reverse text on each line

Reads file(s) <filename>, optionally convert lines to uppercase or lowercase and 
possibly reverses text of each line.

Output is printed to stdout.
"""
import string

def get_convert_func(caseconvert="keep", reverse=False):
    funcs = {"upper": string.upper, "lower": string.lower, "keep": lambda x: x}
    casefunc = funcs[caseconvert]
    if reverse:
        return lambda line: "".join(list(casefunc(line))[::-1])
    else:
        return casefunc

def printfiles(filenames, convert_func):
    for filename in filenames:
        with open(filename) as f:
            for line in f:
                print convertfunc(line.strip("\n"))
```

So far we wrote docstring for the file and the functions to call.

### **`readfile.py` continued**

But real parsing will come (it must be in the same file, put it to the end):

```
if __name__ == "__main__":
    from docopt import docopt
    args = docopt(__doc__)
    print "args", args
    filenames = args["<filename>"]
    caseconvert = "keep"
    if args["--uppercase"]:
        caseconvert = "upper"
    if args["--lowercase"]:
        caseconvert = "lower"
    reverse = args["--reverse"]
    print "--------- Converted file content: ------------"
    convertfunc = get_convert_func(caseconvert, reverse)
    printfiles(filenames, convertfunc)
```

### Trying the code

Finally try it:

```
$ python readfile.py
Usage:
    readfile.py [(--uppercase|--lowercase|--swapcase)] [--reverse] <filename>...
    readfile.py -h
```

Try to see more help:
    $ python readfile.py -h
    Read file (and possibly convert lines)
    Usage:
        readfile.py [(--uppercase|--lowercase|--swapcase)] [--reverse] ...
        readfile.py -h

```
Options:
    -U --uppercase  Convert text to uppercase
    -L --lowercase  Convert text to lowercase
    -S --swapcase   Swap character cases
    -R --reverse    Reverse text on each line

Reads file(s) <filename>, optionally convert lines to uppercase or lowercase and 
possibly reverses text of each line.

Output is printed to stdout.
```

and do some real action:

```
$ python readfile.py -UR readfile.py ../th.py
args {'--lowercase': False,
 '--reverse': True,
 '--swapcase': False,
 '--uppercase': True,
 '-h': False,
 '<filename>': ['readfile.py', '../th.py']}
--------- Converted file content: ------------
)SENIL TREVNOC YLBISSOP DNA( ELIF DAER"""
:EGASU
...>EMANELIF< ]ESREVER--[ ])ESACPAWS--|ESACREWOL--|ESACREPPU--([ YP.ELIFDAER    
H- YP.ELIFDAER    

:SNOITPO
ESACREPPU OT TXET TREVNOC  ESACREPPU-- U-    
ESACREWOL OT TXET TREVNOC  ESACREWOL-- L-    
SESAC RETCARAHC PAWS   ESACPAWS-- S-    
....etc....
```

### Final remarks

- ignore the code performing real action (it is not important, but not for example of command line parsing)
- script file shall have properly formatted docstring - this is source for `docopt` command line parsing rules. These rules must be learned, but they are not so difficult and they are able to express huge amount of different combinations.
- `docopt(__doc__)` is parsing so called docstring, which is read from script file initial `"""(some strint..."""` section.
- result of `docopt` parsing is printed on output to show, what dictionary you get from parsing command line. In production code this would be removed.
- The example was made more complex to show flexibility (asking for one filename would cost us 2 lines of code only if we would not count docstring). Great advantage is, that `docopt` is leading to having very readable (and valid) docstring as essential part of your script.